# URL reg-ex matching problem

Tags: c#, regex

```
<a href="/product.php?id=sdf4j23kj>" rel="nofollow">Product Info</a>
```

I am new to reg-ex. Please help me in match above anchor tags from given HTML document where product id part is changing. In above example only "**sdf4j23kj**" is dynamic.

I am trying this reg-ex

`@"(<a href=""\\/product.php\\?id=)(?<id>)("" rel=""nofollow"">Product Info</a>)"`

Comment: C#? [ ](http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/product\.php\?id=(?<id>[^"]+)"
```

but it is unescaped version , here is the escaped version

```
<a href="/product\\.php\\?id=(?<id>[^"]+)"
```

Also, I should comment that Regex is not suitable to parse html documents. There are lots of comment on this subject. But your case is special, I think that regex is not bad option for you.